# NSDateFormatter subtraction

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter, nsdatepicker

I have a datepicker for the field "From" and "To" and I want the result of the subtraction.
for example: toValue-fromValue and the result would be in hours.
How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference of the two `NSdate` objects can be calculated using `timeIntervalSinceDate`:

```
NSTimeInterval diff = [toDate timeIntervalSinceDate:fromDate];
```

The result is given in seconds. Then, you calculate the hours like this:

```
NSInteger hours = diff / 3600;
```

Comment: It should be noted that NSTimeInterval is an alias for "double" -- a double-precision float.

Comment: I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I tried  with double diff=... but its not working either.

Comment: @user776720 I think you have a memory management problem with your `NSDate` objects. Can you post the code?

Comment: Fixed. I didnt retaining the toDate and fromDate.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two NSDate objects you can compare them using the `timeIntervalSinceDate` method

```
NSDate* fromDate = //Get from date picker
NSDate* toDate = //Get from date picker
NSTimeInterval = [fromDate timeIntervalSinceDate:toDate];
NSInteger hours = timeInterval / 60*60; //60 seconds per minute, 60 minutes per hour
```